# Comparing two binomial survey answers

Tags: binomial-distribution

I am trying to determine if results of a survey question for two different departments is significant. The question is "Were you fully satisfied by the service you received today?" Answer is Yes / No.

Department A: 52% of 141 customers were satisfied with their service

Department B: 67% of 233 customers were satisfied with their service

Is the difference statistically significant? (I am using excel and don't have access to the more fancy stats packages.)

Comment: This will have a binomial distribution if and only if the answers are independent.

Answer (score 3):

Building upon Michael Chernick's comment, if they are independent, you can test this with a standard test comparing two proportions. In R:

```
prop.test( c(73, 156), c(141, 233) ) 

    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

data:  c(73, 156) out of c(141, 233)
X-squared = 7.8991, df = 1, p-value = 0.004946
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
-0.25971681 -0.04387799
sample estimates:
prop 1    prop 2 
0.5177305 0.6695279
```

The p-value is 0.004946